# Pulling Opencart header to wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, opencart

I am trying to get opencart header to wordpress. Opencart is installed within wordpress directory within "store" folder. With some help, I am able to get opencart page into wordpress. The below code is saved as headerX.php and it is called in page.php withing wordpress. This pulls the entire page into wordpress home page. Everything is good uptil now except that `$response->output();` will get the entire opencart page including the products into the main page.

How do I get only the header and footer into wordpress and ignore (or not include) stuff between?

Thanks for any help.

```
<?php

// Configuration
if (file_exists('store/config.php')) {
    require_once('store/config.php');
}  

// VirtualQMOD
require_once('store/vqmod/vqmod.php');
VQMod::bootup();

// VQMODDED Startup
require_once(VQMod::modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'startup.php'));

// Application Classes
require_once(VQMod::modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/customer.php'));
require_once(VQMod::modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/affiliate.php'));
require_once(VQMod::modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/currency.php'));
require_once(VQMod::modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/tax.php'));
require_once(VQMod::modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/weight.php'));
require_once(VQMod::modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/length.php'));
require_once(VQMod::modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/cart.php'));

// Registry
$registry = new Registry();

// Loader
$loader = new Loader($registry);
$registry->set('load', $loader);

// Config
$config = new Config();
$registry->set('config', $config);

// Database 
$db = new DB(DB_DRIVER, DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
$registry->set('db', $db);

// Store
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && (($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') || ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == '1'))) {
    $store_query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "store WHERE REPLACE(`ssl`, 'www.', '') = '" . $db->escape('https://' . str_replace('www.', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/.\\') . '/') . "'");
} else {
    $store_query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "store WHERE REPLACE(`url`, 'www.', '') = '" . $db->escape('http://' . str_replace('www.', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/.\\') . '/') . "'");
}

if ($store_query->num_rows) {
    $config->set('config_store_id', $store_query->row['store_id']);
} else {
    $config->set('config_store_id', 0);
}

// Settings
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "setting WHERE store_id = '0' OR store_id = '" . (int)$config->get('config_store_id') . "' ORDER BY store_id ASC");

foreach ($query->rows as $setting) {
    if (!$setting['serialized']) {
        $config->set($setting['key'], $setting['value']);
    } else {
        $config->set($setting['key'], unserialize($setting['value']));
    }
}

if (!$store_query->num_rows) {
    $config->set('config_url', HTTP_SERVER);
    $config->set('config_ssl', HTTPS_SERVER);   
}

// Url
$url = new Url($config->get('config_url'), $config->get('config_secure') ? $config->get('config_ssl') : $config->get('config_url'));    
$registry->set('url', $url);

// Log 
$log = new Log($config->get('config_error_filename'));
$registry->set('log', $log);

function error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    global $log, $config;

    switch ($errno) {
        case E_NOTICE:
        case E_USER_NOTICE:
            $error = 'Notice';
            break;
        case E_WARNING:
        case E_USER_WARNING:
            $error = 'Warning';
            break;
        case E_ERROR:
        case E_USER_ERROR:
            $error = 'Fatal Error';
            break;
        default:
            $error = 'Unknown';
            break;
    }

    if ($config->get('config_error_display')) {
        echo '<b>' . $error . '</b>: ' . $errstr . ' in <b>' . $errfile . '</b> on line <b>' . $errline . '</b>';
    }

    if ($config->get('config_error_log')) {
        $log->write('PHP ' . $error . ':  ' . $errstr . ' in ' . $errfile . ' on line ' . $errline);
    }

    return true;
}

// Error Handler
set_error_handler('error_handler');

// Request
$request = new Request();
$registry->set('request', $request);

// Response
$response = new Response();
$response->addHeader('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$response->setCompression($config->get('config_compression'));
$registry->set('response', $response); 

// Cache
$cache = new Cache();
$registry->set('cache', $cache); 

// Session
$session = new Session();
$registry->set('session', $session);

// Language Detection
$languages = array();

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "language` WHERE status = '1'"); 

foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
    $languages[$result['code']] = $result;
}

$detect = '';

if (isset($request->server['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) && $request->server['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) { 
    $browser_languages = explode(',', $request->server['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);

    foreach ($browser_languages as $browser_language) {
        foreach ($languages as $key => $value) {
            if ($value['status']) {
                $locale = explode(',', $value['locale']);

                if (in_array($browser_language, $locale)) {
                    $detect = $key;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

if (isset($session->data['language']) && array_key_exists($session->data['language'], $languages) && $languages[$session->data['language']]['status']) {
    $code = $session->data['language'];
} elseif (isset($request->cookie['language']) && array_key_exists($request->cookie['language'], $languages) && $languages[$request->cookie['language']]['status']) {
   $code = $session->data['language'];
} elseif (isset($request->cookie['language']) && array_key_exists($request->cookie['language'], $languages)) {
    $code = $request->cookie['language'];
} elseif ($detect) {
    $code = $detect;
} else {
    $code = $config->get('config_language');
}

if (!isset($session->data['language']) || $session->data['language'] != $code) {
    $session->data['language'] = $code;
}

if (!isset($request->cookie['language']) || $request->cookie['language'] != $code) {      
    setcookie('language', $code, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, '/', $request->server['HTTP_HOST']);
}           

$config->set('config_language_id', $languages[$code]['language_id']);
$config->set('config_language', $languages[$code]['code']);

// Language 
$language = new Language($languages[$code]['directory']);
$language->load($languages[$code]['filename']); 
$registry->set('language', $language); 

// Document
$document = new Document();
$registry->set('document', new Document());         

// Customer
$registry->set('customer', new Customer($registry));

// Affiliate
$registry->set('affiliate', new Affiliate($registry));

if (isset($request->get['tracking'])) {
    setcookie('tracking', $request->get['tracking'], time() + 3600 * 24 * 1000, '/');
}

// Currency
$registry->set('currency', new Currency($registry));

// Tax
$registry->set('tax', new Tax($registry));

// Weight
$registry->set('weight', new Weight($registry));

// Length
$registry->set('length', new Length($registry));

// Cart
$registry->set('cart', new Cart($registry));

//OpenBay Pro
$registry->set('openbay', new Openbay($registry));

// Encryption
$registry->set('encryption', new Encryption($config->get('config_encryption')));

// Front Controller 
$controller = new Front($registry);

// Maintenance Mode
$controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/maintenance'));

// SEO URL's
$controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/seo_url'));    

// Router
if (isset($request->get['route'])) {
    $action = new Action($request->get['route']);
} else {
    $action = new Action('common/home');
}

// Dispatch
$controller->dispatch($action, new Action('error/not_found'));

// Output
$response->output();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do this and this is also a common feature a lot of people are looking for; you can find tons of integrating open cart with wordpress solutions on the internet. Good that it's common.

Have you tried looking into opencart plug in for wordpress?

Wordpress or Opencart, all these system have separate header and footer includes which you can call on other system; you will need to include all the necessary files in order to have it included successfully.

I found this article to be useful: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/opencart-wordpress-integration

You can try the following and give it a shot. (Make sure you fix to the correct path)

**1. Create file headerX.php using the following code and save it to the root directory of your main site (or other location of your choosing outside your OC shop).**

```
<?php
// Config
require_once('shop/config.php');

// VirtualQMOD
require_once('shop/vqmod/vqmod.php');
$vqmod = new VQMod();

// VQMODDED Startup
require_once($vqmod->modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'startup.php'));

// Application Classes
require_once($vqmod->modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/customer.php'));
require_once($vqmod->modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/affiliate.php'));
require_once($vqmod->modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/currency.php'));
require_once($vqmod->modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/tax.php'));
require_once($vqmod->modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/weight.php'));
require_once($vqmod->modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/length.php'));
require_once($vqmod->modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/cart.php'));

$myVar = array();

$myVar = array();

// Registry
$registry = new Registry();

// Loader
$loader = new Loader($registry);
$registry->set('load', $loader);

// Config
$config = new Config();
$registry->set('config', $config);

// Database
$db = new DB(DB_DRIVER, DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
$registry->set('db', $db);

// Url
$url = new Url($config->get('config_url'), $config->get('config_use_ssl') ? $config->get('config_ssl') :

$config->get('config_url'));   
$registry->set('url', $url);

// Log
$log = new Log($config->get('config_error_filename'));
$registry->set('log', $log);

function error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
   global $log, $config;

   switch ($errno) {
      case E_NOTICE:
      case E_USER_NOTICE:
         $error = 'Notice';
         break;
      case E_WARNING:
      case E_USER_WARNING:
         $error = 'Warning';
         break;
      case E_ERROR:
      case E_USER_ERROR:
         $error = 'Fatal Error';
         break;
      default:
         $error = 'Unknown';
         break;
   }

   if ($config->get('config_error_display')) {
      echo '<b>' . $error . '</b>: ' . $errstr . ' in <b>' . $errfile . '</b> on line <b>' . $errline . '</b>';
   }

   if ($config->get('config_error_log')) {
      $log->write('PHP ' . $error . ':  ' . $errstr . ' in ' . $errfile . ' on line ' . $errline);
   }

   return true;
}

// Error Handler
set_error_handler('error_handler');

// Request
$request = new Request();
$registry->set('request', $request);

// Response
$response = new Response();
$response->addHeader('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$response->setCompression($config->get('config_compression'));
$registry->set('response', $response);

// Cache
$cache = new Cache();
$registry->set('cache', $cache);

// Session
$session = new Session();
$registry->set('session', $session);

// Language Detection
$languages = array();

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "language");

foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
   $languages[$result['code']] = $result;
}

$detect = '';

if (isset($request->server['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) && ($request->server['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) {
   $browser_languages = explode(',', $request->server['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);

   foreach ($browser_languages as $browser_language) {
      foreach ($languages as $key => $value) {
         if ($value['status']) {
            $locale = explode(',', $value['locale']);

            if (in_array($browser_language, $locale)) {
               $detect = $key;
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

if (isset($request->get['language']) && array_key_exists($request->get['language'], $languages) &&

$languages[$request->get['language']]['status']) {
   $code = $request->get['language'];
} elseif (isset($session->data['language']) && array_key_exists($session->data['language'], $languages)) {
   $code = $session->data['language'];
} elseif (isset($request->cookie['language']) && array_key_exists($request->cookie['language'], $languages)) {
   $code = $request->cookie['language'];
} elseif ($detect) {
   $code = $detect;
} else {
   $code = $config->get('config_language');
}

if (!isset($session->data['language']) || $session->data['language'] != $code) {
   $session->data['language'] = $code;
}

if (!isset($request->cookie['language']) || $request->cookie['language'] != $code) {    
   setcookie('language', $code, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, '/', $request->server['HTTP_HOST']);
}         

$config->set('config_language_id', $languages[$code]['language_id']);
$config->set('config_language', $languages[$code]['code']);

// Language   
$language = new Language($languages[$code]['directory']);
$language->load($languages[$code]['filename']);   
$registry->set('language', $language);

// Document
$document = new Document();
$registry->set('document', $document);       

// Customer
$registry->set('customer', new Customer($registry));

// Affiliate
$affiliate = new Affiliate($registry);      
$registry->set('affiliate', $affiliate);

if (isset($request->get['tracking']) && !isset($request->cookie['tracking'])) {
   setcookie('tracking', $request->get['tracking'], time() + 3600 * 24 * 1000, '/');
}

// Currency
$registry->set('currency', new Currency($registry));

// Tax
$tax = new Tax($registry);
$registry->set('tax', $tax);

// Weight
$registry->set('weight', new Weight($registry));

// Length
$registry->set('length', new Length($registry));

// Cart
$registry->set('cart', new Cart($registry));

// Front Controller
$controller = new Front($registry);

// Maintenance Mode
$controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/maintenance'));

// SEO URL's
$controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/seo_url'));

// Router
if (isset($request->get['route'])) {
   $action = new Action($request->get['route']);
} else {
   $action = new Action('common/home');
}

// Dispatch
$controller->dispatch($action, new Action('error/not_found'));
```

**2. Include headerX.php in page.php i.e. Place the statement below on line 1 at the very top of page.php**

```
<?php require_once ('headerXYZ.php');?>
```

**3. Right after the opening body tag of your external page.php page add the following code**

```
  <?php
    require_once('shop/catalog/model/total/sub_total.php');
    require_once('shop/catalog/language/english/total/sub_total.php');
    require_once('shop/catalog/model/total/reward.php');
    require_once('shop/catalog/model/total/shipping.php');
    require_once('shop/catalog/model/total/coupon.php');
    require_once('shop/catalog/model/total/tax.php');
    require_once('shop/catalog/model/total/credit.php');
    require_once('shop/catalog/language/english/total/credit.php');
    require_once('shop/catalog/model/total/voucher.php');
    require_once('shop/catalog/model/total/total.php');
    require_once('shop/catalog/language/english/total/total.php');
    foreach($myVar as $key=>$value)
    {
       $$key = $value;
    }

    require_once('shop/catalog/controller/common/header.php');
    require_once('shop/catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.tpl');
    ?>
```

Comment: Well, that is exactly what I have done. If you check my question, I am able to get the opencart page to wordpress. But the issue is that the entire page is pulled into wordpress. As mentioned earlier, '$response->output();' will pull the entire page. How do I make sure I get only the header and not the entire page? By the way, the above code does not work on latest version of opencart and need amendments to headerX.php as I have made in code above.

Comment: ahh, http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-page-in-opencart--cms-22054 or you can checkout this link: http://www.opencartnews.com/tutorials/creating-a-custom-page-in-opencart-part-1/ i like this one: http://blog.arvixe.com/opencart-php-coding-require_once/

Comment: Thanks for all the links. I did go through them all, but none of them answer my question. How do I print the header only?? I do not want all other data printed. Something like `echo $header;` should print opencart header (though this statement does not work there).

Comment: Anybody to answer this?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar, what I did was to write same html/css for footer and header in both systems, after that, I wrote an additional Wordpress plugin to show user and cart info when user is logged in opencart.

Here the plugin:
https://github.com/saRca/op2wp